# iOS App crashes when pressing Button with NavigationController

Tags: ios, button, exc-bad-access, sigabrt, navigationcontroller

I am new to objective-c and I am currently working on an iOS App.
I have a Button i call SettingsButton, that is inside a custom UIView Object.
When I press on this Button the Touch Up Inside handler of the FileOwner "ViewController.m" is called, which later shall push a ViewController on the NavigationController.
But the Application crashes with SIGABRT or EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
This is occurring since I inserted the code with the NavigationController in AppDelegate.m
Any ideas?

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *vc;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

UINavigationController* navController =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
navController.navigationBarHidden = true;
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (IBAction)SettingsPressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"SettingsPressed!");
}
```

To make clear: My intention is only to change view when pressing the SettingsButton and having a Back-Button to return back. But the App already crashes with empty Eventhandler.

**Errormessage** when sigabrt occurs:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString SettingsPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a06fc0'
```

Comment: Can you put the line where it crashes?

Comment: I just added the occurring errormessage from console. Hope that is what you meant.

Comment: Ok, Im getting closer, can I see the piece of code where you call SettingsPressed

Comment: You passed the wrong object to `settingsPressed`.  Figuring out where you did this would be easier if you'd included the traceback.

Comment: thanks for your assistance. SettingsPressed is the IBAction, that is connected to the "Touch Up Inside" Event of my Button.
As I am new to this: How to include the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I just got it solved.
I had to insert a property in AppDelegate.h and synthesize it in AppDelegate.m and then edit it to the following:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *vc;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
_navController.navigationBarHidden = true;
[self.window addSubview:_navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Such a little mistake with such a big effect.
But don't really know why my code above is causing the error. Maybe anyone can clarrify?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are sending the message to the wrong object, run a find in your code to see if you are sending the message SettingsPressed directly to a NSString and check if you made the right connection in interface builder. You could also send in the debugger `po addressOfCrashingInstance` to receive more info.

Comment: I don't really know how to debug this. in console when I type `po addressOfCrashingInstance` I receive `error: use of undeclared identifier 'addressOfCrashingInstance'
error: 1 errors parsing expression`
Connection in interface builder should be fine.

Comment: I was meaning to substitute the word addressOfCrashingInstance with the address of your instance shown in the debugger like po 0x7a06fc0